# command not found - error installing xampp on linux

Tags: linux, xampp

New to this linux, and not sure what I need to do with this error message:

```
~/Downloads$ sudo xampp-linux-*-installer.run
[sudo] password for brent: 
sudo: xampp-linux-x64-7.3.5-1-installer.run: command not found
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here (one that isn't so obvious).

First (the tricky one), the XAMPP installer `xampp-linux-*-installer.run` file is not by default executable; you can see this by running

```
$ ls -l xampp-linux-*-installer.run

-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 148148598 Jun  5 12:35 xampp-linux-x64-7.1.30-0-installer.run
```

Notice how in the permissions section `-rw-r--r--`, the `x` (executable) bit is not set.  Therefore, we must set the `x` bit and then run it with:

```
$ chmod +x xampp-linux-*-installer.run

$ sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```

Notice here that there is a `./` because that installer file is not in any directory contained in `$PATH`.

The `./` indicates the current directory, whereas without `./` your shell will only look through directories specified in `$PATH` for your file.